# Frequency Table Equation

Tags: statistics

The following frequency table shows the sums rolled on a die that was rolled several times. If the median of all values is 3, what is the value of n?

x 1 f 11 (got a 1 eleven times)

x 2 f 6

x 3 f 4

x 4 f n

x 5 f 4

x 6 f 5

Answer is: 5.
I've tried calculating the mean of the f row alone, then that of the x row alone, then both together, I tried calculating the mathematical expectation for every value and then getting the mean of that, but I never get 5 as an answer, and even knowing the answer, I don't know how to solve this.
Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

You may have confused *median* and *mean*.

You have a total of $30+n$ observations so the median observation is at the middle ordered position $15+\frac{n+1}{2}$.

The value $3$ is observed at ordered positions $18,19,20,21$ with the result that  $18 \le 15+\frac{n+1}{2} \le 21$ implying that $5 \le n\le 11$.

So $n=5$ is an answer, in which case you have $35$ observations with the median observation at ordered position $18$ being $3$.

But you could also have $n=11$ as an answer, in which case you have $41$ observations with the median observation at ordered position $21$ being $3$. And similarly you could have $n$ taking any value between $5$ and $11$.